# create common ID for few tables

Tags: sql-server

I have an email table and a phone table and I want to create common customer ID for each email or phone number I insert.

Like if I insert emails: `a@a.a`, `b@b.b`, `c@c.c`, `d@d.d`

and after that I insert phones: `111-111`, `222-222`, `333-333`

I will get:

```
EMAIL | CustomerID
----------------
a@a.a | 1
b@b.b | 2
c@c.c | 3
d@d.d | 4

PHONE | CustomerID
----------------
111-111| 5
222-222| 6
333-333| 7
```

and so on if I keep inserting for each table

EDIT :
i build Costumers table and trigger for inserting email\phone but it work only on the last email\phone each insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_insertEmail]  ON  [dbo].[EmailTB]
instead of INSERT 
as
BEGIN
    declare @Email nvarchar(max);
    select @Email = Email from inserted
    INSERT INTO CostumersTB DEFAULT VALUES
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmailTB] (Email , CostumersID)
            values (@Email , IDENT_CURRENT('[dbo].[CostumersTB]'))  
END
```

Comment: Use SQL SEQUENCES for this purpose. They are independent of the table and work similar to IDENTITY they will give you a new Sequential number everytime. Use it to insert the Value in Primary Key Column

Comment: What happens when a customer has both a phone and an email?

Comment: I question why you think you want to do this?   Don't you have a Customer table??   This sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: Why don't you create a Customer table?

Comment: I would go further and say you want a Customer table, and an SCD CutomerContact allowing you to track changes to phone and email?

Comment: first i got CustomerID table that have only ID column, but i dont need all this numbers except the last one (so i know what the next number to insert)

Comment: when a customer has both a phone and an email? , i check before if the email or phone is exist and if it is, i will take the CustomerID that he had

Comment: Don't focus on the table names, let's assume that is just sample data instead or posting large but irrelevant structures, Type A and B tables with different schema but sharing a single sequence of numbers as ID, focus on the question that is very concrete... @HiravSampat's comment is the answer

Comment: thanks a lot you all! my problem was how to create this ID for each row separately when inserting lot of rows (not 1 by 1), with the another Customer table or without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple rows insertion you need to use a loop (A INSERT-SELECT is not possible since you don't have more values on your customer table to join with the new values), use `OUTPUT` instead of `IDENT_CURRENT` to prevent issues if more than one user is inserting data at same time

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_insertEmail]  ON  [dbo].[EmailTB]
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Email nvarchar(max);
    SELECT Email 
    INTO #Inserted    
    FROM Inserted
    DECLARE @id table(id int)
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Inserted)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Email = Email FROM #Inserted

        DELETE @ID

        INSERT INTO CostumersTB         
        OUTPUT Inserted.CustomersID INTO @id
        DEFAULT VALUES

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmailTB] (Email , CostumersID)
        SELECT @Email , ID FROM @id

        DELETE #Inserted WHERE Email = @Email
    END 
END
```

**PS** Not sure why you discarded this option if it was the first offered one (see question's comments) but I strongly recommend you to use SQL Sequences

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.CustomersSeq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

And use your sequence as default constraint on your tables

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].EmailTB ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Email_CustomerID]  
DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.CustomersSeq) FOR CustomersID
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].PhoneTB ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Phone_CustomerID]  
DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.CustomersSeq) FOR CustomersID
GO
```

Comment: thanks daniel, i will try it. BTW i made another trigger to customers table to delete previous ID after each insert , so it save only the last CustomerID : {CREATE TRIGGER tr_insert_Customer ON CustomersTB AFTER INSERT as DELETE TOP (1) FROM CustomersTB } . is it work fine with this new email trigger?

Comment: @r.tom I'm glad to help you with any solution you choose, as you are the PO, but you can save all that effort just creating a sequence, your application performance will appreciate it

Comment: @r.tom regarding your question, yes, it wil

Comment: thanks again!! i will try Sequences option.  is  there no need of customers table this one, am i right?